# PHP edit variable value edits other variables value

Tags: php, laravel, variables, laravel-5

I'm quite confused about this behavior in PHP and I'm not sure, how to solve it.
I want to do this:
I generate `Object` and use some methods to set its attributes. Then I want to "cache" the object, so I will store it into other variable and then I do something else with the object but it also affects cached object. 
Could you give me some advice, how to do this?

Here is code snippet:

```
$query = new Obj();
$this->item->generateItemsQuery($query);
$this->itemsQuery = $query; // here I "cache" the variable for next usage...

// here I edit the old variable $query
if ($this->getFilter('limit') !== null) {
    $query = $query->limit($this->getFilter('limit'));
}
if ($this->getFilter('page') !== null) {
    $offset = ($this->getFilter('page') - 1) * $this->getFilter('limit');
    $query = $query->offset($offset);
}

public function generateItemsQuery(&$query)
{
     // some other things like this: $query = $query->offset($offset);
}
```

In this example -> problem is, that when I apply method "limit" and "offset" on **$query** it also affect **$this->itemsQuery**

Could you provide me some solution?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to take a look at:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php

Specifically:

> an object variable doesn't contain the object itself as value anymore. It only contains an object identifier which allows object accessors to find the actual object.

If you want to create a clone of the object you will need to do:

`$this->itemsQuery = clone $query;`

See: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php

Comment: Exactly! Thank you very much @craig_h

Comment: @JanKožušník then, please consider setting craig's answer as accepted :)